# phonegap stop playing music in background

Tags: android, cordova, media

I have seen a lot of questions about how to keep playing music in background mode (after the home button is pressed). But what I need is to stop playing music in background mode.

Here is my code.

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    snd = new Media("/android_asset/www/start.mp3", onSuccess, onError, onStatus);
    snd.play(); 
}

function onStatus(status) {
    if( status==Media.MEDIA_STOPPED ) {
        snd.play();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm developing with phonegap, but I don't know who I can't put the tag. I've put cordova instead.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this can answer your questions.

```
document.addEventListener("pause", function() {
    snd.pause();
});
document.addEventListener("resume", function() {
    snd.play();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you play again you must release the Media from output (and close the if), try this:

```
function onStatus(status)
{
    if( status == Media.MEDIA_STOPPED )
    {
        snd.release();
        snd.play();
    }
}
```